# Swift JSON for-in loop

Tags: xcode, loops, swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

I am trying to loop trough a serie of items in a JSON object. However I run into some problems. My code compiles fine without errors but when it gets to the point where the JSON function triggers in stops emulating and gives an error.

This is my code:

```
func getJSON() {
        let urlAsString = "http://localhost:8888/domainchecker/check.php?domain=/google.com"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?

            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if (err != nil) {
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            let arrayFromJson: String! = jsonResult["ITEMS"] as NSString

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                for variable in arrayFromJson {
                    println("DOMAIN");
                }

            })
        })
        jsonQuery.resume()
    }
```

This is the JSON result:

```
{ "ITEMS": [ { "DOMAIN": "google.nl", "AVAILABLE": "NO", "PRICE": "-" }{ "DOMAIN": "google.com", "AVAILABLE": "NO", "PRICE": "-" }{ "DOMAIN": "google.eu", "AVAILABLE": "NO", "PRICE": "-" } ] }
```

and this is the error we receive:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

I have been searching the web for a fix or alternatives, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your JSON structure `jsonResult["ITEMS"]` is not a string as you declared but its an array of dictionaries so you must treat it as array of dictionaries

```
let arrayFromJson: [[String:AnyObject]] = jsonResult["ITEMS"] as [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Comment: This is the line that makes it crash: "var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
"

Comment: Then the server response is not a valid JSON or you are getting the error. Can you check it in your browser?

Comment: zellb, it looks like the JSON result you're showing is an invalid one (it lacks the commas between the dictionaries)